# Unity Firebase messaging not initialising on Android 4.1.2

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Unity game in which I am using the Firebase messaging service in order to send push notifications for.

I'm using the Firebase Unity SDK version 3.0.3

It works on my Galaxy S7, but when I try it on my S2 running Android 4.1.2 Firebase throws an exception when I initialise it.

```
Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;
```

Here are the logs from logcat (adb logcat -s Unity) when I call the above code

```
I/Unity   ( 8751): Firebase App initializing app com.ARTEFICER.fruitfall (default 1).
I/Unity   ( 8751): InitializationException:  Firebase modules failed to initialize: messaging (missing dependency)
I/Unity   ( 8751):   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.CreateAndTrack (Firebase.CreateDelegate createDelegate) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   ( 8751):   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.Create () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   ( 8751):   at Firebase.FirebaseApp.get_DefaultInstance () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   ( 8751):   at Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging+Listener..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   ( 8751):   at Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging+Listener.Create () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   ( 8751):   at Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
I/Unity   ( 8751): Rethrow as TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging
I/Unity   ( 8751):   at FireBaseSetup.Start () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The minimum API level for Firebase is apparently 14. Which 4.1.2 is above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's semi solution.
(https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/unity/client)

```
Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
  var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
  if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
    // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
    // where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += OnTokenReceived;

    // Set a flag here to indicate whether Firebase is ready to use by your app.
  } else {
    UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
      "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
    // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
  }
});
```

Comment: I mean I have no way to test if this would work, as I asked the question over 5 years ago.